# I cannot knit Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I tried to knit the Rmarkdown but the system reports the following error. Can anyone tell me what error I am having and how I can fix it? (The file is the file available in rmarkdown)

```
pandoc.exe: <stdout>: commitBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)
pandoc.exe: <stdout>: commitBuffer: invalid argument (cannot encode character '\7853')
  |.................                                          |  29% [setup]   

processing file: test.Rmd
                                                                                                     
output file: test.knit.md

"C:/PROGRA~1/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.html --lua-filter "C:\Users\Thuận\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\Thuận\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --embed-resources --standalone --variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --template "C:\Users\Thuận\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --include-in-header "C:\Users\THUN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6PJX5N\rmarkdown-str59dc75265874.html" 
pandoc.exe: recoverEncode: invalid argument (cannot encode character '\7853')
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) :
  running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc.exe" --version' had status 1
2: In system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/Pandoc/pandoc.exe" --version' had status 1
Execution halted
```

This is my first time using Rmarkdown so I encountered many difficulties. I hope to receive help from everyone.

Comment: When you run all, did you get the error too?

Comment: This is the original file when I first open the Rmarkdown, and when I knit it, it caused that error. (Ofcourse, I installed and loaded the library rmarkdown)

Comment: I mean , you can run per chunck on R markdown file right? Did you find error when running those chunks?

Comment: It always shows that error whether I knit all or any chunks.

Comment: We're trying to figure out if the error is something in your document or in your set-up. Is this a document you wrote/edited, or the default one? If not the default, the first thing to try is to make a new Quarto document and attempt to render the default template that RStudio creates. If that doesn't work, then we need to debug your set-up/installation. If that does work, then we'll probably need you to post some of your document to figure out what isn't working in it.

Comment: This is the default document from Rstudio, and I didn't edit it.

Comment: It looks like potentially a problem with your `pandoc` installation. I'd suggest re-installing RStudio (which comes with `pandoc`, I believe)

Comment: I installed pandoc-3.1.9-windows-x86_64, but I don't know how to apply it in Rstudio? Can you help me to do the next steps?